# How to process image with raw resolution in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have calculated the NIRv across tropical forests using high-spatial-resolution (4.7 meter) Planet data (NICFI). Then, I want to calculate the spatial variance of NIRv at 1-hectare scale. So I further calculated the shannon index of NIRv within each moving window of 20*20 piexl (about 100m*100m) through the function 'kernel()' and 'entropy()' on GEE.

Since the 4.7-meter image across the whole tropics is very large, I then resampled the result of shannon index to 1-km resolution and download it.

You can view code that illustrates my problem [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c836b30df17aa857c15f6f1ec5873b7f) (https://code.earthengine.google.com/c836b30df17aa857c15f6f1ec5873b7f):

```
// calculate NDVI,NIRv
function VI(img) {
  var ndvi=img.normalizedDifference(['N','R']);
  var nir=img.select('N').divide(10000);
  var nirv=img.expression("NIR*(NDVI-0.08)",{"NIR":nir,"NDVI":ndvi});
  return img.addBands(ndvi.rename('NDVI'))
            .addBands(nirv.rename('NIRv'));
}

// calculate cv&shannon
var k=20;
var weights_k=ee.List.repeat(ee.List.repeat(1,k),k); // set up a k*k kernels
var kernel_k=ee.Kernel.fixed(k,k,weights_k,1,1,false);
var kernel_meter=ee.Kernel.square(50,'meters',false);

function FD(img) {
  var shannon_nirv = img.select('NIRv')
                        .unitScale(0, 1)
                        .multiply(255)
                        .toByte()
                        .entropy(kernel_meter);

  
  return img.addBands(shannon_nirv.rename('shannon_nirv'));

}

// 1. calculate NDVI,NIRv,FD
var ame_img= ee.ImageCollection("projects/planet-nicfi/assets/basemaps/americas")
                      .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-12-01','2021-11-30'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12, 5,'month'))
                      .map(VI)
                      .map(FD)
                      .median();
var asia_img= ee.ImageCollection("projects/planet-nicfi/assets/basemaps/asia")
                      .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-12-01','2021-11-30'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12, 5,'month'))
                      .map(VI)
                      .map(FD)
                      .median();                   
var africa_img= ee.ImageCollection("projects/planet-nicfi/assets/basemaps/africa")
                      .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-12-01','2021-11-30'))
                      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(12, 5,'month'))
                      .map(VI)
                      .map(FD)
                      .median(); 

var tropic_img = ee.ImageCollection([ame_img, asia_img, africa_img])
                              .mosaic();

// Export
var roi=ee.Geometry.Rectangle(
  [
    [-110, -25],
    [180, 25]
  ],'EPSG:4326',false);

// std_nirv
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:tropic_img.select('shannon_nirv').multiply(100).toUint16(), // raster file to be exported
  description: 'shannon_nirv_1km',
  folder: 'Planet', // good drive folder name
  fileNamePrefix: 'shannon_nirv_1km', // export name name
  scale: 1000,  //resolution
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF', // export format
  maxPixels: 1e13, // can increase this to 1e15 if max is reached
  region: roi // clip the boundary
});
```

However, I found that the results of shannon index might not be calculated along the 4.7-m-size pixel but probably on the 1-km scale. To verify this phenomenon, I collected some point representing biodiversity. I first compared biodiversity against shannon index directly on GEE (using reduceRegions) and found a significant correlation (R2=0.2). By contrast, when comparing biodiversity with shannon index downloaded locally, the correlation is not significant (R2<0.02).

Code for extracting shannon index by point:

```
var keilData = ee.FeatureCollection('users/***/biodiversity_point')
var keilData_buffer=subdata.map(function(f) {return f.buffer(5)});
var shannon_index=tropic_img.select('shannon_nirv')
                        .reduceRegions({
                          collection:keilData_buffer,
                          reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
                          scale:5
                        });

// Chart  
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(shannon_index, 'mean', ['Biodiversity'])
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({ pointSize: 2, pointColor: 'red', width: 500, height: 500, titleX: 'shannon_nirv', titleY: 'S',
  trendlines: {
        0: {
          type: 'linear',
          color: 'lightblue',
          lineWidth: 3,
          opacity: 0.7,
          showR2: true,
          visibleInLegend: true
        },
        1: {
          type: 'linear',
          color: 'pink',
          lineWidth: 3,
          opacity: 0.7,
          showR2: true,
          visibleInLegend: true
        }
      },
    
  })
   
print(chart)
```

I guess that GEE just conducted the function 'entropy' at the scale of output resolution (that is 1-km).

I do not know how to conducte the above analysis using the raw resolution (i.e., 4.7 meter) rather than resampled scale by GEE, and then aggregate them to coarse resolution. In other word, how to calculate shannon index of 4.7-meter NIRv within a hectare in GEE?

**What we are expecting:**
I would like to run the function 'entropy()' along Planet image with its nominalScale (i.e., 4.7 m) rather than other coarse resolution. Then, I want to aggrgate the result to 1-km resolution and download it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dive into your function processing the data.
But the general approach to using raw resolution is to take the projection info from some random layer and apply it as the parameter for saving:

```
# Set data source
var shannon_nirv = img.select('NIRv');
var projection = shannon_nirv.first().projection().getInfo();

# Save data
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: merged_band,
  region: roi,
  folder: dir,
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform
});
```

Hope, it helps!